# Linear functions versus Logarithmic and Exponential functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, average

If a function is linear, I know that this should be true:

$$ {f(x_2)-f(x_1)}={f(\bar x)} $$

Where $\bar x$ is the point exactly in between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Now, I know from looking at their graphs that the same shouldn't be true for logarithmic and exponential functions. That is, for logarithmic functions:

$$ {f(x_2)-f(x_1)}<{f(\bar x)} $$

And for exponential functions:

$$ {f(x_2)-f(x_1)}>{f(\bar x)} $$

I'm not a mathematician by formation, but I feel like it should be possible to prove this without having to look at their graph. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you are aiming at *convexity*... however your notation is a bit off. For instance even in the linear case your formula doesn't make much sense: suppose $f(x) = x$, then $f(1)-f(0) = 1 - 0 = 1 \neq 1/2 = f(1/2) $... Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function if that is what you are looking for!

Comment: You are right, this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo:  I think OP meant $f(x_2)+f(x_1) \over 2$ = $f(\frac {x_2+x_1} 2),$ and I'd like to see your comment developed into an answer

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have answered the question using your assumption :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statements are hinting at something called [convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function); however, your notation is a bit off:  as it is now, the statements don't hold even for simple cases. I'm going to assume that you intended to talk about convexity and answer myself :)

A function is said to be *convex* if, for any two points $x$ and $y$ and any $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then
$$ f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).$$
Note, in particular, that this means that the value of the function at the midpoint of $x$ and $y$ is smaller than the midpoint of the values of the function at $x$ and $y$:
$$ f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}.$$

If a function is not convex it may be *concave*, if 
$$ f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \geq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).$$

If a function is *both* convex and concave, then it is *linear*. Note that there are functions that are neither convex nor concave!

In the examples you allude to, we have that the linear function is (clearly) linear, so 
$$ f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).$$

Let's look at the exponential function $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$; this is a convex function, so in this case we would have 
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y} \leq \lambda \mathrm{e}^x + (1-\lambda)\mathrm{e}^y.$$

The general proof requires derivatives and Taylor expansions; however, for the midpoint, the proof is very easy. In this case we have to prove that
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x+y}{2}} \leq \frac{\mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^y}{2},$$
for all $x$ and $y$. Consider the following steps
$$ \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x+y}{2}} \leq \frac{\mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^y}{2}$$
$$ 2\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x+y}{2}} \leq \mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^y$$
$$ 2\mathrm{e}^{x/2}\mathrm{e}^{y/2} \leq \mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^y$$
$$ 0 \leq \mathrm{e}^x - 2 \mathrm{e}^{x/2}\mathrm{e}^{y/2} + \mathrm{e}^y$$
$$ 0 \leq \left(\mathrm{e}^{x/2} - \mathrm{e}^{y/2}\right)^2$$
Note that the right hand side is a square, so the inequality holds for all $x$ and $y$!

The logarithm function, on the other hand, is *concave*, so the reverse inequality holds: for all positive $x$ and $y$,
$$\log\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \geq \frac{\log(x) + \log(y)}{2}.$$
We can easily prove this with the following chain of inequalities:
$$\log\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \geq \frac{\log(x) + \log(y)}{2}$$
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \exp\left(\frac{\log(x) + \log(y)}{2}\right)$$
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \exp\left(\frac{\log(x)}{2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{\log(y)}{2}\right)$$
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \exp\left(\log(\sqrt{x})\right)\exp\left(\log(\sqrt{y})\right)$$
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$$
$$x+y \geq 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$$
$$x+y - 2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y} \geq 0$$
$$\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right)^2 \geq 0,$$
which, again, is true for all (positive) $x$ and $y$!

Comment: +1.  Very nice.  This is what OP was looking for per the comments.  Thank you

Comment: Indeed, this is exactly what I was looking for. Jensen's inequality in the context of probability theory, in particular, should solve the problem that I was having. Thank you for putting me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) =  ax + b$ for some $a, b, \in \mathbb{R}\,/\,\{0\}$ then 
\begin{align}
f(x_2) - f(x_1) &=ax_1 + b - ax_2 -b \\
&= a(x_2 - x_1)
\end{align}
Now, you write

> $\bar{x}$ is the point exactly in between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Which means 
$$\bar{x} = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2}$$

Where, wlog, $x_2 > x_1$.

Now
\begin{align}
f(\bar{x}) &= a \left( \frac{x_2 - x_1}{2} \right) + b \\
&= \frac{a}{2}(x_2 - x_1) + b\\
&\neq f(x_2)-f(x_1)
\end{align}

Comment: I think OP meant to say that for linear functions $f(\frac {x_2-x_1} 2) = \frac {f(x_2)-f(x_1)} 2 +b,$ and you didn't address exponential or logarithmic functions

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Your comment is the exact basis on which I proposed my answer; the fact that the inital 'linear' case fails, means the remainder of the OP's questions breaks down. If the OP wishes to include my suggestion as a case upon which s(he) states a new formulation for the exponential / logarithmic case then that is up to them.

Comment: Also, the point between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is $(x_1 \mathbf +  x_2)/2=x_1+(x_2-x_1)/2$ (my comment above followed your error)